# What is the difference between synchronized and static synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

For a travel booking web application, where there are 100 concurrent users logged in,
should ticket booking and generating an "E-Ticket Number" be implemented by a "synchronized" or a "static synchronized" method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, are you aware of the difference between a static method and an instance method in general?

The only difference that `synchronized` makes is that before the VM starts running that method, it has to acquire a monitor. For an instance method, the lock acquired is the one associated with the object you're calling the method on. For a static method, the lock acquired is associated with the type itself - so no other threads will be able to call any other synchronized static methods at the same time.

In other words, this:

```
class Test
{
    static synchronized void Foo() { ... }

    synchronized void Bar() { ... }
}
```

is *roughly* equivalent to:

```
class Test
{
    static void Foo()
    {
        synchronized(Test.class)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    void Bar()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Generally I tend not to use synchronized methods at all - I prefer to explicitly synchronize on a private lock reference:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

...

void Bar()
{
    synchronized(lock)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You haven't provided nearly enough information to determine whether your method should be a static or instance method, or whether it should be synchronized at all. Multithreading is a complex issue - I strongly suggest that you read up on it (through books, tutorials etc).

Comment: If for travel booking web site, there are 100 concurrent users. Then Ticket Booking & generating "E-Tickect Number" functionality should be implemented in "synchronized" block or "static synchronized" block?

Comment: Both your question and this comment that repeats it make no sense. if Jon Skeet's excellent answer did not fulfill your needs, please rephrase your question.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How is it "roughly" equivalent? I was under the impression that the effective execution is the same (even though "synchronized" on the method is turned into a flag instead of some bytecode instructions (which the synchronized block is turned into)).

Comment: @Joachim: I have a **feeling** that the JVM makes sure that the thread doesn't even enter a synchronized method *at all* until it's acquired the lock - so if it's deadlocked, a stack trace would show the calling method at the top level. With the synchronization *in* the method, that method would be at the top. I could be wrong though - and there could be other subtleties I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Jon's answer covers the difference hinted at in your question title.

However, I would say that **neither** should be used for generating a ticket number.  On the assumption that these are being stored in a database, somewhere - the database should be responsible for generating the number when you insert the new record (presumably by an autoincrementing primary key, or something similar).

Failing that, if you *must* generate the number within Java code, I suspect that the synchronisation overhead might be quite noticeable with 100 concurrent users.  If you are running on Java 1.5 or later, I'd use a `java.util.concurrent.AtomicInteger` to get the ticket number, which you can simply call as

```
private static final AtomicInteger ticketSequence;

static
{
    final int greatestTicket = getHighestExistingTicketNumber(); // May not be needed if you can start from zero each time
    ticketSequence = new AtomicInteger(greatestTicket + 1);
}

public /*static*/ int getNextTicketNumber()
{
    return ticketSequence.incrementAndGet();
}
```

This gives you the concurrent global uniqueness you need in a much more efficient fashion than synchronizing every time you need an integer.