# Thread Acquired level

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I am not clear the concept of

> Java Thread acquires an **object level lock** when it enters into an instance synchronized java method and acquires a **class level lock** when it enters into static synchronized java method.

What does it mean When it says object level lock and class level lock ?

**For example:**

```
 public class Counter{
      private static int count = 0;
      private int count2 = 0;

      public static synchronized int getCount(){
           return count;
      }
      public synchronized setCount(int count2){
           this.count2 = count2;
      }
 }
```

getCount() here will lock Counter.class object while setCount() will lock on current object(this). What does that ***this*** refer to ? Does that mean when getCount() get called another thread can't access setCount() since the whole class is locked ?

Comment: This is well documented.  What reading did you do?   Here's a good start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654654/static-synchronized-and-non-static-synchronized-methods-in-threads

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do synchronized static methods work in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578904/how-do-synchronized-static-methods-work-in-java)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536064/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronized-and-static-synchronized

Comment: just another way of asking the question

Comment: That's why it is a duplicate.

Comment: By the way, `this.count` is misleading code on a non-static method -- it make it look like `count` is an instance (ie, non-static) field. The only way someone would read that correctly is if they thought to mistrust the code and double check that `count` is an instance method. Qualifying static fields/methods via a reference is a bad habit to get into, because it conveys the wrong meaning. For instance, this will *not* throw a NPE: `Counter counter = null; counter.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it mean When it says object level lock and class level lock ?

When you lock on a `static` method you are locking on the `Class` object itself and there is one of these per `ClassLoader`.  In your example,

```
public static synchronized int getCount(){
```

This is locking on the `Counter.class` object and is the same as:

```
public static int getCount() {
    synchronized (Counter.class) {
    }
```

If you are instead locking on a method that is *not* `static` then you are locking on the instance of the object that owns that method.  In your example:

```
public synchronized void setCount(int count){
```

This is the same as locking on the particular `Counter` instance and is equivalent to:

```
public void setCount(int count){
    synchronized (this) {
       ...
```

So if you have 2 `Counter` objects, `counter1` and `counter2`, and 1 thread is calling `counter1.getCount()` and the other is calling `counter2.getCount()` at the same time, then they will both lock on the same `Class` object and one will block the other.

But if the 2 threads are instead calling `counter1.setCount(...)` and `counter2.setCount()` they will be locking on different objects -- `counter1` and `counter2` respectively.  They will not block each other.

As mentioned, it is very bad form to have asymmetry on your setters and getters and it is unusual to have either be `static`.

> Does that mean when getCount() get called another thread can't access setCount() since the whole class is locked ?

No.  If `getCount()` is called, the `Counter.class` is locked and when `setCount(...)` is called `counter1` or `counter2` is locked.  The only time a lock blocks a thread is when the *same object* has been locked by another thread.  Just because there is a lock on `Counter.class` does *not* mean that there is some sort of uber-class lock.  The only time that will block another thread is if it too locks on `Counter.class`.

I'd take a moment to read Sun's [great documentation on how `synchronized` works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: So what does it mean by locking Counter.class. What does it block ?

Comment: Locking on any object (the .class or an instance) does not block anything.  The only time there is a block is when some other thread locks the _same_ object.  So if `Counter.class` is locked, another thread will block if it goes to also lock `Counter.class` at the same time.  Have you read the link I posted @user1389813?

Comment: yes i read all the links that you posted (those duplicates and the sun java tutorial), and I just want to confirm about this last thing: when you put a lock on Counter.class, it will only block threads that are trying to accessing another 'static' method not 'non-static' method, and object level lock will be the other way around, correct ?

Comment: Yes.  When you put a lock on `Counter.class` (by calling a `synchronized static` method) it will only block threads that also call a `synchronized static` method at the same time.  Calling `synchronized` instance methods block other threads that also call a `synchronized` instance method at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, each class and each instance of a class are endowed with their intrinsic locks. These are the locks acquired and release on entry to and exit from `synchronized` methods.

As usual `this` refers to the instance on which `setCount()` was called and because each instance has its own intrinsic lock the second call to `setCount()` will not block as long as it is invoked on another instance of your class, but an attempt to call `setCount()` on an instance on which another `setCount()` call is in progress will block.

Class lock and instance locks are different and thus `getCount()` and `setCount()` never get in each others way.

Comment: I am not that clear about class lock, so in which case will a class lock block another thread ?

Comment: A thread will block on entering `getCount()` if another thread's call to `getCount()` is in progress (i.e. another thread has acquired but not yet released the class level intrinsic lock).

Comment: Yes. In fact, since `getCount()` is a static method, you're not really calling it on an instance (even if it looks so syntactically), but on the class.

Comment: I think im kind of get it, so 2 threads call Counter.getCount(), and one of the thread will be blocked and have to wait, correct ?

Comment: Yes. The second one will wait until the first leaves the method.

Answer (score 1):

`static` members are associated to the class not to a particular instance. As a result a synchronization on a `static` member effectively synchronizes over the whole class as static is a class member

instance members are associated with instances of the class (e.g. the intrisic `this` lock) so if you synchronize on a member field (non-static) or on `this` then you have a lock associated with an instance object.

In your example `getCount` synchronizes on the intrinsik lock of the class. Effectively you are doing:

```
public setCount(int count){
    synchronized(this){
        this.count = count;
    }  
}
```

You would be synchronizing in a class level if you did:

```
static Object count = new Object();  
synchronized(count){  

}
```

Comment: so whenever you put a lock or synchronize a static variable that it will automatically become a class level lock ?

Comment: Yes.Because it is associated to the class not an instance

Comment: no matter where you put it (outside the class or inside the class), correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Each object in Java has a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion).  Since a `class` is represented by an object of type `java.lang.Class`, each class has a mutex too.  `synchronized` instance methods lock the instance's mutex, while `synchronized static` methods lock the mutex for the corresponding `java.lang.Class` instance.

```
class C {
  synchronized T myMethod() { ... }

  static synchronized T myStaticMethod() { ... }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class C {
  T myMethod() {
    synchronized (this) { ... }  // An object level lock.
  }

  static T myStaticMethod() {
    synchronized (C.class) { ... }  // A class level lock
    // is really just an object level lock an a Class.
  }
}
```

---

Once you know what object you're synchronizing on, you can understand the `synchronized` keyword by breaking it down.

```
synchronized (x) {
  body();
}
```

performs like

```
monitorenter(x);  // locks x or throws NullPointerException if x is null.
try {
  body();
} finally {
  monitorexit(x);  // unlocks x
}
```

where `monitorenter` and `monitorexit` are [Java bytecode instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) that respectively block until they acquire the mutex, and release the mutex.

Since `synchronized` introduces a "protected region", like `try ... finally`, the lock will be released even if an exception is thrown, though [killing the thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) will leave the lock unreleased possibly leading to [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).